Como guardar una cookie en un proyecto ya desplegado?
tengo un proyecto en el que creo un token con jsonwebtoken y después lo guardo en las cookies, en local funciona perfectamente, pero al desplegar el proyecto tanto en Vercel como en Render, no consigo que desde el backend envie el token a las cookies, os dejo algunos fragmentos de codigo, a ver si alguien me puede echar una mano ?
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.sign(
      payload,
      process.env.TOKEN_SECRET, 
      {
        expiresIn: "1d",
      },
      (error, token) => {
        error ? reject(error) : resolve(token);
      }
    );
  });
} 

export const authRequired = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token) {
    res.json({ message: "no autorizado" });
  } else {

   
    jwt.verify(token, TOKEN_SECRET, (error, user) => {
      if (error) {
        res.json({ message: "Error" });
      }
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  }
};


Yo uso localStorage es fácil de usar
Así guardas la info:
localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(user.token));

Así obtienes la info:
localStorage.getItem("token")

podrías probar si te sirve así.
